# Tables with some cells having special marks

Tags: tables, math-mode

I have the following simple document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand{\st}{\subseteq}
\newcommand{\sst}{\subsetneq}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering$}m{1cm}<{$}}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|M|M|M|M|M|}
\hline
     & K  & G    & H    & L    \tabularnewline\hline
K    &    & \st  & \st  & \st  \tabularnewline\hline
G    &    &      & \sst & \sst \tabularnewline\hline
G    &    &      &      & \sst \tabularnewline\hline
L    &    &      &      &      \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In which all columns have the same width. I would like to add to some cells (the ones that use `\subsetneq`) a special symbol, e.g. (a), (b), (c). Indeed, I need to refer to these cells as cases in my proof.

I would like to do this without using a `\footnote` because my table contains math and footnotes might be thought as exponents and obscure things.

Ideally, the symbol would be in (very) small font and located in the "south east corner" of the cells (so that it is clear that the symbols are not indices). I want all columns to have a constant width whether or not they contain a cell with a mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work (not tested with hyperref or cleveref)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand{\st}{\subseteq}
\newcommand{\sst}{\subsetneq}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{1cm}<{$}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\marker[1]{\rlap{\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\tiny(#1)}}\def\@currentlabel{(#1)}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|M|M|M|M|M|}
\hline
  & K & G             & H             & L             \\\hline
K &   & \st\marker{a} & \st\marker{b}\label{item:b} & \st\marker{c} \\\hline
G &   &               & \sst          & \sst          \\\hline
G &   &               &               & \sst          \\\hline
L &   &               &               &               \\\hline
\end{tabular}

The inclusing in \ref{item:b} shows ...


 \end{document}
```

Comment: I'd probably also remove most of the lines as well

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Yes, lines were only there to make the cells quite visible.

Comment: Ooops. Seems that the addition of a mark slightly perturbs the centering of the main symbol. This is clear in the H column of the reply. I cannot understand why.

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow

Comment: That is because `\st` *sees* something after it. If `\st` and `\sst` are only used in this table redefine them as `{\subseteq}` etc (extra braces), then they are ordinary and does not add extra space (as they do as relations)

Comment: Right indeed. I would like to be in position approve again : but I have already done so.